# flutter doctor: No devices available

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I have my device connected, but flutter cannot detect it. **My developer options are on and USB debugging is also on**.

- My android version is 6.0.1

Just so you know, I haven't installed the android SDK on my machine. Could that be the reason why it isn't detected?

- I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

when I run `flutter doctor` it says `no available devices`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install android platform tools ??

Try `sudo apt install android-tools-adb`

Then try `adb devices` to check if your device is listed

Comment: thanks bro, that fixed my error. thanks a lot. much appretiated

Comment: i got an issue, when i run ```flutter run``` the app doesn't pop up on my device

Comment: have u tried to turn on usb debugging secure settings in some devices in developer settings there are additional settings that need to be enabled

Comment: i enabled everything that needs to be enableed